# Adding a new model to an existing aws api gateway using CDK and Typescript

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I have an API gateway defined in a cdk project and I have exported the RestApi. In a different project, I'm trying to add a few Models to this API gateway but I get an error.
Here is how the import line:

```
const restApi = apiGateway.RestApi.fromRestApiId(this,"MyGatewayApi",props.restApiId);
```

and when I try to add a model I get this error:

> Property 'addModel' does not exist on type 'IRestApi'.

Here is the code that uses the restApi:

```
const errorModel = restApi.addModel('errorModel', {
      contentType: 'application/json',
      modelName: 'Error',
      schema: {
        schema: apiGateway.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
        title: 'Error',
        type: apiGateway.JsonSchemaType.OBJECT,
        properties: {
          errorId: {type: apiGateway.JsonSchemaType.STRING} ,
        }
      }
    });
```

Then I changed my import line to this :

```
const restApi = apiGateway.RestApi.fromRestApiId(this,"MyGatewayApi",props.restApiId) as apiGateway.RestApi;
```

and the IDE doesn't show any errors. But the problem is when I run cdk synth it returns another error:

> const errorModel = restApi.addModel('errorModel', {
> ^ TypeError: restApi.addModel is not a function

Does anybody know what's wrong? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a model with the `Model` constructor.  The `restApi` prop accepts the `IRestApi` type:

```js
const errorModel = new apigw.Model(this, "errorModal", {
    restApi,
    schema: {},
});
```

The `addModel` method isn't exposed on the `IRestApi` [interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces) type returned by the `fromRestApiId` method.  This is an implemenation choice, not an underlying constraint.  [Under the hood](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/bbbd9b2539f56a17a1a768f0628a4da6f023bc69/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/restapi.ts#L804-L808), `addModel` just calls the `Model` constructor as we do above.

Comment: Thank you @fedonev it helped a lot! Just to make your answer more precise, after applying your solution I received another error: "Error: root is not configured when imported using `fromRestApiId()`. Use `fromRestApiAttributes()` API instead." But when I changed `fromRestApiId()` to `fromRestApiAttributes()`, it worked perfectly!